# count and echo json format wordpress database

Tags: json

I am trying to count all birth years, months and days separately using get_results. I can also print them.

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$userـmeta} WHERE `meta_key` = 'birthday' ")
```

output:

```
                             Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 134
            [user_id] => 1
            [meta_key] => birthday
            [meta_value] => a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"1920";s:5:"month";s:1:"6";s:3:"day";s:2:"16";}
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 172
            [user_id] => 4
            [meta_key] => birthday
            [meta_value] => a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"1952";s:5:"month";s:1:"3";s:3:"day";s:2:"14";}
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 279
            [user_id] => 8
            [meta_key] => birthday
            [meta_value] => a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"1999";s:5:"month";s:1:"4";s:3:"day";s:2:"13";}
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 284
            [user_id] => 5
            [meta_key] => birthday
            [meta_value] => a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"2015";s:5:"month";s:1:"3";s:3:"day";s:1:"9";}
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 289
            [user_id] => 6
            [meta_key] => birthday
            [meta_value] => a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"1945";s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"17";}
        )

)
```

Comment: Those meta values are *serialized* strings and not JSON-encoded. But even if they were JSON-encoded, you would still need to run a `foreach` loop and do something like `$years['1920']++`, `$months['6']++` and `$days['16']++` for each meta value. I.e. Add the year/month/day to the years/months/days array (defined outside the loop) and then increment their count in each iteration. However, you should instead ask on Stack Overflow for generic PHP/programming questions like this.

Comment: Also, if the meta value was saved in a standard date format like `Y-m-d`, e.g. `1920-06-16`, you could do string splitting like `$data = explode( '-', $meta_value );` which is faster than doing `$data = unserialize( $meta_value );`.